# Using the apply family in R to pass each row of a 2-column dataframe to a function I made?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I have a little dataframe with two columns: `fp` (False Positive) and `fn` (false negative), like so:

```
falsepos <- c(.05, .25, .5)
falseneg <- c(.01, .05, .1)
x_name <- "fp"
y_name <- "fn"

df <- data.frame(falsepos,falseneg)
names(df) <- c(x_name, y_name)
```

I've also written a little adaptation of Bayes's Rule as a function, like so:

```
bayesrule <- function(baserate = .03, 
                      fp, 
                      fn) {
    output <- (baserate * (1 - fn)) / ((baserate * (1 - fn)) + ((1 - baserate) * (fp)))

    return(output)
}
```

`fp` and `fn` stand for the same thing they did in `df`. In this function, `bayesrule`, I've left a default value for the `baserate` of `.03`. My question is: how can I write some `R` code - likely using the `apply` family of functions, I'm guessing, but maybe something else - to pass each each row in `df`'s value for `fp` and `fn` into their corresponding place in the `bayesrule` function, yielding me three Bayes's Rule calculations (each with the same default `baserate` of .03)?

I've looked at similar posts in SX and have gotten quite close, but I'm just shy of the mark on this. I've gotten as close as this:

`sapply(df,FUN = bayesrule,fn=df$fn, fp=df$fp)`

But no closer.

Comment: Is there a reason `bayesrule(fp=df$fp, fn=df$fn)` doesn't work? It provides the same output as any combination of `sapply`, `apply`, or `mapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything row-wise here:

```r
bayesrule(fp=df$fp, fn=df$fn)
# [1] 0.37979540 0.10516605 0.05273438
```

Since all of the math internally is already ready for R's vectorized efficiencies, you can pass vectors. It will be far more efficient (calling `bayesrule` *once*) than trying to call it once per row.

Comment: Thanks very much. In typical fashion, I was thinking this was going to be more complex than the reality. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, if the function is not vectorized and is dependent on multiple  parameters of length > 1, we can use `Map`/`mapply`

```
unlist(Map(bayesrule, fn = df$fn, fp = df$fp))
```

---

Or `Vectorize` the function and apply the columns

```
Vectorize(bayesrule)(fn = df$fn, fp = df$fp)
#[1] 0.37979540 0.10516605 0.05273438
```

Here, the function is already vectorized as the operation showed in the function is a vectorized operation in `R` (It is also mentioned in the comment -@r2evans comments).  So, it can be directly applied

```
with(df, bayesrule(fp=fp, fn = fn))
#[1] 0.37979540 0.10516605 0.05273438
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(new = bayesrule(fp = fp, fn = fn))
```

---

With `sapply`, it is looping over each column individually

Comment: Thanks for the `dplyr` bit -- that's where I wanted to end up!